# After delete database ,my Django does't work

Tags: python, django

I have some problem with my database, so I deleted `db.sqlite3` and `Migrations` manually.

than I recreate the database by using `manage.py makemigrations <appname> manage. py migrate <appname>`

Everything looks normal，but when I get into localhost:8000, It is a blank page without anything (even if I never change the templates).

To my confused, I can get into the admin page. 
Are there any mistakes in this process？what happened to my django app?

Comment: First, you shouldn't need to delete your `migrations` files unless you've managed to seriously break some stuff with wonky table changes. That said, since you've already re-run `makemigrations`, the command to re-create your database will be `python manage.py migrate`.  This command will take your existing database migrations and apply them. You don't want to specify your app in this case using `migrate <appname>` because all of your tables, even the django ones, need to be recreated. If this does not work for you, give us a traceback of the error that occurs when you attempt it.

Comment: Have you startup the server? Are there any errors in the log?

Comment: What happens when you run `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @DragonBobZ I have regretted it after I deleted `db.sqlite3` and `migrations in my app directory` . After deleted them,if I run `makemigrations`, it return `No changes detected`,then run `python manage.py migrate`,it returns `Applying auth ,admin and so on....` , it doesn't seem to have added me app models in the database, and I can't see a migrations directory in my app.So when I get into localhost:8000, it raises error `no such table: blog_post`.  If I try `makemigrations <appname>`,then`python manage.py migrate`,the migrations diretory created, but when I get into localhost , it is a blank

Comment: @hsfzxjy already start , It looks like the database is causing this problem

Comment: @guillermochamorro it doesn't raise error, everything is ok, no warm

Comment: @DumplingsYang do you have `DEBUG = True` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: @DragonBobZ I alread solved the blank page problem, It seems like the problems caused by git,after I return the version one weeks ago, it started to work again. Anyway,thank to your suggestions :) ,I won't delete database next time.

Answer (score 0):

Now what you can do is :

**1) Take backup of your code**

**2) Create another project with other name or same name, it will have it's own sqlite db**

**3) Place your code in that project and then run migrations, it will recreate your db schema.**

And it should work.

Comment: It seems like the problems caused by git,not the database,after I return the version one weeks ago, it started to work again. Anyway,thank to your suggestions :)

Comment: @DumplingsYang haha, ok.

Answer (score 0):

Simply
DROP DATABASE 
delete you migrations folder inside of your project folder
run ./manage.py makemigrations
run ./manage.py migrate

Just reset the whole thing from scratch if you don't care about any of the data inside the database